# Why won't IvyGen work?

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to add ivy to a building I'm working on. I tried using the IvyGen add-on, but it doesn't come up when I pressed SHIFT A. I tried using another similar add-on to see if it was just IvyGen. The other add-on showed up in the menu that comes up when I press SHIFT A. What do I do? The IvyGen add-on isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Not all add-ons are exactly the same and they are not necessarily to be found in the *Add* menu. For *IvyGen* make sure you have the sidepanel visible in the *3D Viewport*, if not press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring it up. There under the *Create* tab you will find the *Ivy Generator*.

[image: sidepanel ivygen]

Comment: Just as a quick addition to Gordon's answer, it's always worth clicking the addon's dropdown in Preferences when you add a new addon. In this case it spectifcally says where you can access the ivy generator under 'Location' and of course you can access the documentation in the blender manual from there too.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes, good addition. Not all add-ons (especially third-party add-ons) are documented well, but it can definitely help sometimes.

Comment: Why is it that I always see spelling mistakes in my postings after the 5 minute limit for correcting them? :^))

Comment: @JohnEason Same here ;)